# VBA Match variable range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with the `.Match` function. If I set a range inside it with quotes and letters ("A:A") it goes well. But when I try to set it with variable, it gives a 1004 error.

This works:

```
a = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("A1"), Sheets("Data").Range("A:A"), 0)
```

This doesn't work:

```
a = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("A2"), Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(a, 4), Cells(a + 5, 4)), 0)
```

How do I set a range with variables in a `.Match` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use fully qualified (up to `worksheet` object) `range` references, otherwise they default to currently "active" sheet

```
  a = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("A2"), Sheets("Data").Range(Sheets("Data").Cells(a, 4), Sheets("Data").Cells(a + 5, 4)), 0)
```

Comment: however I have a variable range, so is it possible to find another way to set it with cells property, may be?

Comment: It is a different issue from the question posted, isn't it? If so then make a new post. In the meanwhile you may want to accept the answer if it solved your _original_ question. Thank you

Comment: @GasiakA. - if you have a variable range, change the value of the variable `a` (or change the hard-coded `5` and `4` to be variables if they are the bits that need to change)

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to use Resize() here:

```
a = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("A2"), _
                            Sheets("Data").Cells(a, 4).Resize(6, 1), 0)
```